# Can someone please translate this for me? I’ve had a piece of metal with this written on it for years but have no idea what it says!

Tags: translation

Can someone please translate this for me? I’ve had a piece of metal with this written on it for years but have no idea what it says!
[image]

Comment: I assume that you have no background in Chinese? Even so, your writing is extremely legible, and a handwriting recognition app (e.g. Google Translate’s handwriting pad) will be more than enough to get the right characters.

Comment: I tried using that and it translated it to “Lutheran” which I didn’t think was right because my family has no Lutheran background

Comment: simplified characters: 信义

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text that you’ve copied off the metal is「信義」, which means *(good) faith*, as in the phrase *acting in good faith*. Translating the characters individually, it is「信」*(belief)* and「義」*(morality, principles)*.